# How can I build "tomee 7.0.5 plume" Docker image using openjdk 10? -or is this not possible?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, apache-tomee, java-10

**How can I build "tomee 7.0.5 plume" Docker image using openjdk 10?

- or is this not possible?**

Thought I could do so by editing the Dockerfile located at...

https://github.com/tomitribe/docker-tomee/blob/29e41238711b95a407434783a84cadf1c4630f6e/8-jre-7.0.5-plume/Dockerfile

*(note: the edited "Dockerfile" is listed below... -just changed the openjdk version to 10)*

...but, result is always:  returned a non-zero code: 7

**Ran the build command like this...**

```
    docker build -t tomee10 .
```

**Output looks like this...**

```
    BBEKOFT@AAXA22A747 /cygdrive/c/tools/tomee10_stuff
    $ docker build -t tomee10 .
    Sending build context to Docker daemon  11.78kB
    Step 1/9 : FROM openjdk:10-jre
     ---> 996f362f73b9
    Step 2/9 : ENV PATH /usr/local/tomee/bin:$PATH
     ---> Running in 9bf64e59f639
    Removing intermediate container 9bf64e59f639
     ---> 7e37b0fe7fd0
    Step 3/9 : RUN mkdir -p /usr/local/tomee
     ---> Running in 36c396da9335
    Removing intermediate container 36c396da9335
     ---> ddb4e7361df6
    Step 4/9 : WORKDIR /usr/local/tomee
    Removing intermediate container fc840f7153ba
     ---> 67293830ce94
    Step 5/9 : ENV GPG_KEYS     223D3A74B068ECA354DC385CE126833F9CF64915     678F2D98F1FD9643811639FB622B8F2D043F71D8     7A2744A8A9AAF063C23EB7868EBE7DBE8D050EEF     82D8419BA697F0E7FB85916EE91287822FDB81B1     9056B710F1E332780DE7AF34CBAEBE39A46C4CA1     A57DAF81C1B69921F4BA8723A8DE0A4DB863A7C1     B7574789F5018690043E6DD9C212662E12F3E1DD     B8B301E6105DF628076BD92C5483E55897ABD9B9     BDD0BBEB753192957EFC5F896A62FC8EF17D8FEF     C23A3F6F595EBD0F960270CC997C8F1A5BE6E4C1     D11DF12CC2CA4894BDE638B967C1227A2678363C     DBCCD103B8B24F86FFAAB025C8BB472CD297D428     F067B8140F5DD80E1D3B5D92318242FE9A0B1183     FAA603D58B1BA4EDF65896D0ED340E0E6D545F97
     ---> Running in 2f21c75ec995
    Removing intermediate container 2f21c75ec995
     ---> 093ff03dc636
    Step 6/9 : RUN set -xe     && for key in $GPG_KEYS; do         gpg --keyserver pgp.mit.edu --keyserver-options http-proxy=proxy.apps.dhs.gov:80 --recv-keys "$key";     done
     ---> Running in 5a053e4ce201
    + gpg --keyserver pgp.mit.edu --keyserver-options http-proxy=proxy.apps.dhs.gov:80 --recv-keys 223D3A74B068ECA354DC385CE126833F9CF64915
    gpg: directory '/root/.gnupg' created
    gpg: keybox '/root/.gnupg/pubring.kbx' created
    gpg: key E126833F9CF64915: 4 signatures not checked due to missing keys
    gpg: /root/.gnupg/trustdb.gpg: trustdb created
    gpg: key E126833F9CF64915: public key "Richard Kenneth McGuire (CODE SIGNING KEY) <rickmcguire@apache.org>" imported
    gpg: no ultimately trusted keys found
    gpg: Total number processed: 1
    gpg:               imported: 1
    + gpg --keyserver pgp.mit.edu --keyserver-options http-proxy=proxy.apps.dhs.gov:80 --recv-keys 678F2D98F1FD9643811639FB622B8F2D043F71D8
    gpg: key 622B8F2D043F71D8: public key "Jean-Louis Monteiro (CODE SIGNING KEY) <jlmonteiro@apache.org>" imported
    gpg: Total number processed: 1
    gpg:               imported: 1
    + gpg --keyserver pgp.mit.edu --keyserver-options http-proxy=proxy.apps.dhs.gov:80 --recv-keys 7A2744A8A9AAF063C23EB7868EBE7DBE8D050EEF
    gpg: key 8EBE7DBE8D050EEF: 3 signatures not checked due to missing keys
    gpg: key 8EBE7DBE8D050EEF: public key "Jarek Gawor (CODE SIGNING KEY) <gawor@apache.org>" imported
    gpg: no ultimately trusted keys found
    gpg: Total number processed: 1
    gpg:               imported: 1
    + gpg --keyserver pgp.mit.edu --keyserver-options http-proxy=proxy.apps.dhs.gov:80 --recv-keys 82D8419BA697F0E7FB85916EE91287822FDB81B1
    gpg: key E91287822FDB81B1: 1 signature not checked due to a missing key
    gpg: key E91287822FDB81B1: public key "Mark Struberg (Apache) <struberg@apache.org>" imported
    gpg: no ultimately trusted keys found
    gpg: Total number processed: 1
    gpg:               imported: 1
    + gpg --keyserver pgp.mit.edu --keyserver-options http-proxy=proxy.apps.dhs.gov:80 --recv-keys 9056B710F1E332780DE7AF34CBAEBE39A46C4CA1
    gpg: key CBAEBE39A46C4CA1: 45 signatures not checked due to missing keys
    gpg: key CBAEBE39A46C4CA1: public key "Matt Hogstrom <hogstrom@apache.org>" imported
    gpg: no ultimately trusted keys found
    gpg: Total number processed: 1
    gpg:               imported: 1
    + gpg --keyserver pgp.mit.edu --keyserver-options http-proxy=proxy.apps.dhs.gov:80 --recv-keys A57DAF81C1B69921F4BA8723A8DE0A4DB863A7C1
    gpg: key A8DE0A4DB863A7C1: public key "Romain Manni-Bucau <rmannibucau@tomitribe.com>" imported
    gpg: Total number processed: 1
    gpg:               imported: 1
    + gpg --keyserver pgp.mit.edu --keyserver-options http-proxy=proxy.apps.dhs.gov:80 --recv-keys B7574789F5018690043E6DD9C212662E12F3E1DD
    gpg: key C212662E12F3E1DD: 1 signature not checked due to a missing key
    gpg: key C212662E12F3E1DD: public key "David Blevins <dblevins@apache.org>" imported
    gpg: no ultimately trusted keys found
    gpg: Total number processed: 1
    gpg:               imported: 1
    + gpg --keyserver pgp.mit.edu --keyserver-options http-proxy=proxy.apps.dhs.gov:80 --recv-keys B8B301E6105DF628076BD92C5483E55897ABD9B9
    gpg: key 5483E55897ABD9B9: 2 signatures not checked due to missing keys
    gpg: key 5483E55897ABD9B9: public key "Jarek Gawor <gawor@apache.org>" imported
    gpg: no ultimately trusted keys found
    gpg: Total number processed: 1
    gpg:               imported: 1
    + gpg --keyserver pgp.mit.edu --keyserver-options http-proxy=proxy.apps.dhs.gov:80 --recv-keys BDD0BBEB753192957EFC5F896A62FC8EF17D8FEF
    gpg: key 6A62FC8EF17D8FEF: public key "Romain Manni-Bucau <rmannibucau@apache.org>" imported
    gpg: Total number processed: 1
    gpg:               imported: 1
    + gpg --keyserver pgp.mit.edu --keyserver-options http-proxy=proxy.apps.dhs.gov:80 --recv-keys C23A3F6F595EBD0F960270CC997C8F1A5BE6E4C1
    gpg: key 997C8F1A5BE6E4C1: 5 signatures not checked due to missing keys
    gpg: key 997C8F1A5BE6E4C1: public key "Xu Hai Hong (Ivan Xu @ Geronimo) <xhhsld@gmail.com>" imported
    gpg: no ultimately trusted keys found
    gpg: Total number processed: 1
    gpg:               imported: 1
    + gpg --keyserver pgp.mit.edu --keyserver-options http-proxy=proxy.apps.dhs.gov:80 --recv-keys D11DF12CC2CA4894BDE638B967C1227A2678363C
    gpg: key 67C1227A2678363C: public key "Romain Manni-Bucau <rmannibucau@apache.org>" imported
    gpg: Total number processed: 1
    gpg:               imported: 1
    + gpg --keyserver pgp.mit.edu --keyserver-options http-proxy=proxy.apps.dhs.gov:80 --recv-keys DBCCD103B8B24F86FFAAB025C8BB472CD297D428
    gpg: key C8BB472CD297D428: public key "Jonathan Gallimore <jgallimore@apache.org>" imported
    gpg: Total number processed: 1
    gpg:               imported: 1
    + gpg --keyserver pgp.mit.edu --keyserver-options http-proxy=proxy.apps.dhs.gov:80 --recv-keys F067B8140F5DD80E1D3B5D92318242FE9A0B1183
    gpg: key 318242FE9A0B1183: public key "Jeremy Whitlock <jwhitlock@apache.org>" imported
    gpg: Total number processed: 1
    gpg:               imported: 1
    + gpg --keyserver pgp.mit.edu --keyserver-options http-proxy=proxy.apps.dhs.gov:80 --recv-keys FAA603D58B1BA4EDF65896D0ED340E0E6D545F97
    gpg: key ED340E0E6D545F97: public key "Andy Gumbrecht (TomEE Code Signing) <agumbrecht@tomitribe.com>" imported
    gpg: Total number processed: 1
    gpg:               imported: 1
    Removing intermediate container 5a053e4ce201
     ---> 2112f839516f
    Step 7/9 : RUN set -x   && curl -fSL https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/tomee/apache-tomee/7.0.5/apache-tomee-7.0.5-plume.tar.gz.asc -o tomee.tar.gz.asc   && curl -fSL https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/tomee/apache-tomee/7.0.5/apache-tomee-7.0.5-plume.tar.gz -o tomee.tar.gz   && gpg --batch --verify tomee.tar.gz.asc tomee.tar.gz   && tar -zxf tomee.tar.gz        && mv apache-tomee-plume-7.0.5/* /usr/local/tomee       && rm -Rf apache-tomee-plume-7.0.5      && rm bin/*.bat         && rm tomee.tar.gz*
     ---> Running in e48a17dabf11
    + curl -fSL https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/tomee/apache-tomee/7.0.5/apache-tomee-7.0.5-plume.tar.gz.asc -o tomee.tar.gz.asc
      % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                     Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
      0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:20 --:--:--     0curl: (7) Failed to connect to repo.maven.apache.org port 443: Connection refused
    The command '/bin/sh -c set -x  && curl -fSL https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/tomee/apache-tomee/7.0.5/apache-tomee-7.0.5-plume.tar.gz.asc -o tomee.tar.gz.asc   && curl -fSL https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/tomee/apache-tomee/7.0.5/apache-tomee-7.0.5-plume.tar.gz -o tomee.tar.gz   && gpg --batch --verify tomee.tar.gz.asc tomee.tar.gz   && tar -zxf tomee.tar.gz        && mv apache-tomee-plume-7.0.5/* /usr/local/tomee       && rm -Rf apache-tomee-plume-7.0.5      && rm bin/*.bat         && rm tomee.tar.gz*' returned a non-zero code: 7

    BBEKOFT@AAXA22A747 /cygdrive/c/tools/tomee10_stuff
    $
```

**Here is the edited Dockerfile (modified the openjdk version)...**

```
    FROM openjdk:10-jre

    ENV PATH /usr/local/tomee/bin:$PATH
    RUN mkdir -p /usr/local/tomee

    WORKDIR /usr/local/tomee

    # curl -fsSL 'https://www.apache.org/dist/tomee/KEYS' | awk -F ' = ' '$1 ~ /^ +Key fingerprint$/ { gsub(" ", "", $2); print $2 }' | sort -u
    ENV GPG_KEYS \
        223D3A74B068ECA354DC385CE126833F9CF64915 \
        678F2D98F1FD9643811639FB622B8F2D043F71D8 \
        7A2744A8A9AAF063C23EB7868EBE7DBE8D050EEF \
        82D8419BA697F0E7FB85916EE91287822FDB81B1 \
        9056B710F1E332780DE7AF34CBAEBE39A46C4CA1 \
        A57DAF81C1B69921F4BA8723A8DE0A4DB863A7C1 \
        B7574789F5018690043E6DD9C212662E12F3E1DD \
        B8B301E6105DF628076BD92C5483E55897ABD9B9 \
        BDD0BBEB753192957EFC5F896A62FC8EF17D8FEF \
        C23A3F6F595EBD0F960270CC997C8F1A5BE6E4C1 \
        D11DF12CC2CA4894BDE638B967C1227A2678363C \
        DBCCD103B8B24F86FFAAB025C8BB472CD297D428 \
        F067B8140F5DD80E1D3B5D92318242FE9A0B1183 \
        FAA603D58B1BA4EDF65896D0ED340E0E6D545F97

    RUN set -xe \
        && for key in $GPG_KEYS; do \
            gpg --keyserver pgp.mit.edu --keyserver-options http-proxy=myproxy_url:80 --recv-keys "$key"; \
        done

    RUN set -x \
        && curl -fSL https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/tomee/apache-tomee/7.0.5/apache-tomee-7.0.5-plume.tar.gz.asc -o tomee.tar.gz.asc \
        && curl -fSL https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/tomee/apache-tomee/7.0.5/apache-tomee-7.0.5-plume.tar.gz -o tomee.tar.gz \
        && gpg --batch --verify tomee.tar.gz.asc tomee.tar.gz \
        && tar -zxf tomee.tar.gz \
        && mv apache-tomee-plume-7.0.5/* /usr/local/tomee \
        && rm -Rf apache-tomee-plume-7.0.5 \
        && rm bin/*.bat \
        && rm tomee.tar.gz*

    EXPOSE 8084
    CMD ["catalina.sh", "run"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Worked when I modified Dockerfile like this…**

```
    FROM openjdk:10-jre

    ENV PATH /usr/local/tomee/bin:$PATH
    RUN mkdir -p /usr/local/tomee

    WORKDIR /usr/local/tomee

    # curl -fsSL 'https://www.apache.org/dist/tomee/KEYS' | awk -F ' = ' '$1 ~ /^ +Key fingerprint$/ { gsub(" ", "", $2); print $2 }' | sort -u
    ENV GPG_KEYS \
        223D3A74B068ECA354DC385CE126833F9CF64915 \
        678F2D98F1FD9643811639FB622B8F2D043F71D8 \
        7A2744A8A9AAF063C23EB7868EBE7DBE8D050EEF \
        82D8419BA697F0E7FB85916EE91287822FDB81B1 \
        9056B710F1E332780DE7AF34CBAEBE39A46C4CA1 \
        A57DAF81C1B69921F4BA8723A8DE0A4DB863A7C1 \
        B7574789F5018690043E6DD9C212662E12F3E1DD \
        B8B301E6105DF628076BD92C5483E55897ABD9B9 \
        BDD0BBEB753192957EFC5F896A62FC8EF17D8FEF \
        C23A3F6F595EBD0F960270CC997C8F1A5BE6E4C1 \
        D11DF12CC2CA4894BDE638B967C1227A2678363C \
        DBCCD103B8B24F86FFAAB025C8BB472CD297D428 \
        F067B8140F5DD80E1D3B5D92318242FE9A0B1183 \
        FAA603D58B1BA4EDF65896D0ED340E0E6D545F97

    RUN set -xe \
        && for key in $GPG_KEYS; do \
            gpg --keyserver pgp.mit.edu --keyserver-options http-proxy=<your proxy url:port> --recv-keys "$key" || \
            gpg --keyserver keyserver.pgp.com --keyserver-options http-proxy=<your proxy url:port> --recv-keys "$key" || \
            gpg --keyserver ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net --keyserver-options http-proxy=<your proxy url:port> --recv-keys "$key" ; \  
        done

    RUN set -x \
        && curl -fSL https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/tomee/apache-tomee/7.0.5/apache-tomee-7.0.5-plume.tar.gz.asc --proxy <your proxy url>:80 -o tomee.tar.gz.asc \
        && curl -fSL https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/tomee/apache-tomee/7.0.5/apache-tomee-7.0.5-plume.tar.gz --proxy <your proxy url>:80 -o tomee.tar.gz \
        && gpg --batch --verify tomee.tar.gz.asc tomee.tar.gz \
        && tar -zxf tomee.tar.gz \
        && mv apache-tomee-plume-7.0.5/* /usr/local/tomee \
        && rm -Rf apache-tomee-plume-7.0.5 \
        && rm bin/*.bat \
        && rm tomee.tar.gz*

    EXPOSE 8084
    CMD ["catalina.sh", "run"]
```

**(1)**

*change to the directory with the Dockerfile file*

```
    $ docker build -t tomee10 .
```

**(2)**

```
    $ docker run -it --rm -p 8888:8084 -v tomeevolume:/usr/local/tomee b21587558d62 /bin/bash
```

*i.e.,  where b21587558d62  is the “IMAGE_ID”*

**(3)**

update server.xml as needed:

```
    docker cp server.xml cbff3129c954:/usr/local/tomee/conf/server.xml
```

*(note:  cbff3129c954 comes from my prompt:    root@cbff3129c954:/usr/local/tomee#  )*

*i.e. where “server.xml” looks like this…*

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
        <!-- TomEE plugin for Tomcat -->
        <Listener className="org.apache.tomee.catalina.ServerListener" />
        <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener" />
        <!--APR library loader. Documentation at /docs/apr.html -->
        <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on" />
        <!-- Prevent memory leaks due to use of particular java/javax APIs-->
        <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener" />
        <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener" />
        <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener" />

        <GlobalNamingResources>
            <Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
                      type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
                      description="User database that can be updated and saved"
                      factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
                      pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />
        </GlobalNamingResources>

        <Service name="Catalina">

            <Connector port="8084" protocol="HTTP/1.1" connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="8443" xpoweredBy="false" server="Apache TomEE" />
            <Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />

            <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">
                <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
                    <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm" resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
                </Realm>
                <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
                    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs" prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt" pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />
                </Host>
            </Engine>
        </Service>
    </Server>
```

**(4)**

update tomcat-users.xml as needed:

```
    docker cp tomcat-users.xml cbff3129c954:/usr/local/tomee/conf/tomcat-users.xml
```

*(note:  cbff3129c954 comes from my prompt:    root@cbff3129c954:/usr/local/tomee#  )*

*i.e., where tomcat-users.xml looks like this…*

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <tomcat-users xmlns="http://tomcat.apache.org/xml" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://tomcat.apache.org/xml tomcat-users.xsd" version="1.0">
                    <role rolename="tomcat"/>
                    <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
                    <role rolename="admin-gui"/>
                    <role rolename="tomee-admin" />
                    <user username="tomcat" password="s3cret" roles="tomcat,manager-gui,admin-gui,tomee-admin"/>
                    <user username="tomee" password="s3cret" roles="tomcat,manager-gui,admin-gui,tomee-admin" />
    </tomcat-users>
```

**(5)**

update context.xml as needed:

```
    docker cp context.xml cbff3129c954:/usr/local/tomee/webapps/manager/META-INF/context.xml
```

*(note:  cbff3129c954 comes from my prompt:    root@cbff3129c954:/usr/local/tomee#  )*

*i.e.,  where context.xml looks like this…*

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Context antiResourceLocking="false" privileged="true" >
                    <!--
                    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve" allow="127\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+|::1|0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1" />
                    -->
                    <Manager sessionAttributeValueClassNameFilter="java\.lang\.(?:Boolean|Integer|Long|Number|String)|org\.apache\.catalina\.filters\.CsrfPreventionFilter\$LruCache(?:\$1)?|java\.util\.(?:Linked)?HashMap"/>
    </Context>
```

**(6)**

```
    $ docker run -it --rm -p 8888:8084 -v tomeevolume:/usr/local/tomee b21587558d62 /bin/bash
    root@33c49b8920ec:/usr/local/tomee# cd bin
    root@33c49b8920ec:/usr/local/tomee/bin# ./catalina.sh run
    Using CATALINA_BASE:   /usr/local/tomee
    Using CATALINA_HOME:   /usr/local/tomee
    Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /usr/local/tomee/temp
    Using JRE_HOME:        /docker-java-home
    Using CLASSPATH:       /usr/local/tomee/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/local/tomee/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
    NOTE: Picked up JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS:  --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMED
    13-Aug-2018 18:22:12.153 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.persistence.PersistenceBootstrap.getDefaultProvider Default JPA Provider changed to org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider specified by jar:file:/usr/local/tomee/lib/openejb-core-eclipselink-7.0.5.jar!/META-INF/org.apache.openejb.persistence.PersistenceBootstrap.provider
    WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
    WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.apache.tomee.catalina.ServerListener (file:/usr/local/tomee/lib/tomee-catalina-7.0.5.jar) to field java.lang.reflect.Field.modifiers
    WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.apache.tomee.catalina.ServerListener
    WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
    WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
    13-Aug-2018 18:22:12.828 INFO [main] jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke Server version:        Apache Tomcat (TomEE)/8.5.32 (7.0.5)
    13-Aug-2018 18:22:12.828 INFO [main] jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke Server built:          Jun 20 2018 19:50:35 UTC
    13-Aug-2018 18:22:12.828 INFO [main] jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke Server number:         8.5.32.0
    13-Aug-2018 18:22:12.828 INFO [main] jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke OS Name:               Linux
    13-Aug-2018 18:22:12.828 INFO [main] jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke OS Version:            4.9.87-linuxkit-aufs
    13-Aug-2018 18:22:12.829 INFO [main] jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke Architecture:          amd64
    13-Aug-2018 18:22:12.829 INFO [main] jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke Java Home:             /usr/lib/jvm/java-10-openjdk-amd64
    13-Aug-2018 18:22:12.829 INFO [main] jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke JVM Version:           10.0.2+13-Debian-1
    13-Aug-2018 18:22:12.829 INFO [main] jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
    13-Aug-2018 18:22:12.829 INFO [main] jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke CATALINA_BASE:         /usr/local/tomee
    13-Aug-2018 18:22:12.829 INFO [main] jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke CATALINA_HOME:         /usr/local/tomee
    13-Aug-2018 18:22:12.830 INFO [main] jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
    13-Aug-2018 18:22:12.830 INFO [main] jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED
    13-Aug-2018 18:22:12.830 INFO [main] jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke Command line argument: --add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMED
    13-Aug-2018 18:22:12.830 INFO [main] jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/usr/local/tomee/conf/logging.properties
    13-Aug-2018 18:22:12.831 INFO [main] jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
    13-Aug-2018 18:22:12.832 INFO [main] jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke Command line argument: -javaagent:/usr/local/tomee/lib/openejb-javaagent.jar
    13-Aug-2018 18:22:12.832 INFO [main] jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
    13-Aug-2018 18:22:12.832 INFO [main] jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke Command line argument: -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources
    13-Aug-2018 18:22:12.833 INFO [main] jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke Command line argument: -Dorg.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener.UMASK=0027
    13-Aug-2018 18:22:12.833 INFO [main] jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke Command line argument: -Dignore.endorsed.dirs=
    13-Aug-2018 18:22:12.833 INFO [main] jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/usr/local/tomee
    13-Aug-2018 18:22:12.833 INFO [main] jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/usr/local/tomee
    13-Aug-2018 18:22:12.834 INFO [main] jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/usr/local/tomee/temp
    13-Aug-2018 18:22:12.834 INFO [main] jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [/usr/java/packages/lib:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/jni:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/jni:/lib:/usr/lib]
    13-Aug-2018 18:22:12.934 INFO [main] jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8084"]
    13-Aug-2018 18:22:12.953 INFO [main] jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
    13-Aug-2018 18:22:12.963 INFO [main] jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
    13-Aug-2018 18:22:12.968 INFO [main] jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
    13-Aug-2018 18:22:13.487 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.util.OptionsLog.info Using 'openejb.jdbc.datasource-creator=org.apache.tomee.jdbc.TomEEDataSourceCreator'
    13-Aug-2018 18:22:13.609 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.OpenEJB$Instance.<init> ********************************************************************************
    13-Aug-2018 18:22:13.609 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.OpenEJB$Instance.<init> OpenEJB http://tomee.apache.org/
    13-Aug-2018 18:22:13.609 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.OpenEJB$Instance.<init> Startup: Mon Aug 13 18:22:13 UTC 2018
    13-Aug-2018 18:22:13.610 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.OpenEJB$Instance.<init> Copyright 1999-2018 (C) Apache OpenEJB Project, All Rights Reserved.
    13-Aug-2018 18:22:13.610 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.OpenEJB$Instance.<init> Version: 7.0.5
    13-Aug-2018 18:22:13.610 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.OpenEJB$Instance.<init> Build date: 20180710
    13-Aug-2018 18:22:13.610 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.OpenEJB$Instance.<init> Build time: 12:28
    13-Aug-2018 18:22:13.610 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.OpenEJB$Instance.<init> ********************************************************************************
    13-Aug-2018 18:22:13.610 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.OpenEJB$Instance.<init> openejb.home = /usr/local/tomee
    13-Aug-2018 18:22:13.610 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.OpenEJB$Instance.<init> openejb.base = /usr/local/tomee
    13-Aug-2018 18:22:13.614 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.cdi.CdiBuilder.initializeOWB Created new singletonService org.apache.openejb.cdi.ThreadSingletonServiceImpl@42721fe
    13-Aug-2018 18:22:13.615 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.cdi.CdiBuilder.initializeOWB Succeeded in installing singleton service
    13-Aug-2018 18:22:13.661 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.config.ConfigurationFactory.init TomEE configuration file is '/usr/local/tomee/conf/tomee.xml'
    13-Aug-2018 18:22:13.715 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.config.ConfigurationFactory.configureService Configuring Service(id=Tomcat Security Service, type=SecurityService, provider-id=Tomcat Security Service)
    13-Aug-2018 18:22:13.718 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.config.ConfigurationFactory.configureService Configuring Service(id=Default Transaction Manager, type=TransactionManager, provider-id=Default Transaction Manager)
    13-Aug-2018 18:22:13.722 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.util.OptionsLog.info Using 'openejb.deployments.classpath=false'
    13-Aug-2018 18:22:13.726 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createRecipe Creating TransactionManager(id=Default Transaction Manager)
    13-Aug-2018 18:22:13.791 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createRecipe Creating SecurityService(id=Tomcat Security Service)
    13-Aug-2018 18:22:13.882 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.server.ServiceManager.initServer Creating ServerService(id=cxf)
    13-Aug-2018 18:22:14.094 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.server.ServiceManager.initServer Creating ServerService(id=cxf-rs)
    13-Aug-2018 18:22:14.167 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.server.SimpleServiceManager.start   ** Bound Services **
    13-Aug-2018 18:22:14.168 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.server.SimpleServiceManager.printRow   NAME                 IP              PORT
    13-Aug-2018 18:22:14.168 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.server.SimpleServiceManager.start -------
    13-Aug-2018 18:22:14.168 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.server.SimpleServiceManager.start Ready!
    13-Aug-2018 18:22:14.170 INFO [main] jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke Initialization processed in 1926 ms
    13-Aug-2018 18:22:14.241 INFO [main] org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBNamingContextListener.bindResource Importing a Tomcat Resource with id 'UserDatabase' of type 'org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase'.
    13-Aug-2018 18:22:14.241 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createRecipe Creating Resource(id=UserDatabase)
    13-Aug-2018 18:22:14.246 INFO [main] jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke Starting service [Catalina]
    13-Aug-2018 18:22:14.247 INFO [main] jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat (TomEE)/8.5.32 (7.0.5)
    13-Aug-2018 18:22:14.267 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke Deploying web application directory [/usr/local/tomee/webapps/manager]
    13-Aug-2018 18:22:14.285 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.init ------------------------- localhost -> /manager
    13-Aug-2018 18:22:14.623 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.openejb.config.ConfigurationFactory.configureApplication Configuring enterprise application: /usr/local/tomee/webapps/manager
    13-Aug-2018 18:22:14.692 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.openejb.config.AppInfoBuilder.build Enterprise application "/usr/local/tomee/webapps/manager" loaded.
    13-Aug-2018 18:22:14.702 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication Assembling app: /usr/local/tomee/webapps/manager
    13-Aug-2018 18:22:14.783 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.deployWebApps using context file /usr/local/tomee/webapps/manager/META-INF/context.xml
    13-Aug-2018 18:22:14.787 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication Deployed Application(path=/usr/local/tomee/webapps/manager)
    13-Aug-2018 18:22:14.984 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
    13-Aug-2018 18:22:15.125 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke Deployment of web application directory [/usr/local/tomee/webapps/manager] has finished in [858] ms
    13-Aug-2018 18:22:15.126 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke Deploying web application directory [/usr/local/tomee/webapps/docs]
    13-Aug-2018 18:22:15.127 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.init ------------------------- localhost -> /docs
    13-Aug-2018 18:22:15.177 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.openejb.config.ConfigurationFactory.configureApplication Configuring enterprise application: /usr/local/tomee/webapps/docs
    13-Aug-2018 18:22:15.184 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.openejb.config.AppInfoBuilder.build Enterprise application "/usr/local/tomee/webapps/docs" loaded.
    13-Aug-2018 18:22:15.185 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication Assembling app: /usr/local/tomee/webapps/docs
    13-Aug-2018 18:22:15.196 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication Deployed Application(path=/usr/local/tomee/webapps/docs)
    13-Aug-2018 18:22:15.262 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
    13-Aug-2018 18:22:15.283 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke Deployment of web application directory [/usr/local/tomee/webapps/docs] has finished in [157] ms
    13-Aug-2018 18:22:15.284 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke Deploying web application directory [/usr/local/tomee/webapps/ROOT]
    13-Aug-2018 18:22:15.285 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.init ------------------------- localhost -> /
    13-Aug-2018 18:22:15.327 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.openejb.config.ConfigurationFactory.configureApplication Configuring enterprise application: /usr/local/tomee/webapps/ROOT
    13-Aug-2018 18:22:15.341 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.openejb.config.AppInfoBuilder.build Enterprise application "/usr/local/tomee/webapps/ROOT" loaded.
    13-Aug-2018 18:22:15.342 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication Assembling app: /usr/local/tomee/webapps/ROOT
    13-Aug-2018 18:22:15.360 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication Deployed Application(path=/usr/local/tomee/webapps/ROOT)
    13-Aug-2018 18:22:15.460 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
    13-Aug-2018 18:22:15.496 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke Deployment of web application directory [/usr/local/tomee/webapps/ROOT] has finished in [213] ms
    13-Aug-2018 18:22:15.497 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke Deploying web application directory [/usr/local/tomee/webapps/host-manager]
    13-Aug-2018 18:22:15.503 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.init ------------------------- localhost -> /host-manager
    13-Aug-2018 18:22:15.552 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.openejb.config.ConfigurationFactory.configureApplication Configuring enterprise application: /usr/local/tomee/webapps/host-manager
    13-Aug-2018 18:22:15.568 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.openejb.config.AppInfoBuilder.build Enterprise application "/usr/local/tomee/webapps/host-manager" loaded.
    13-Aug-2018 18:22:15.569 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication Assembling app: /usr/local/tomee/webapps/host-manager
    13-Aug-2018 18:22:15.580 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.deployWebApps using context file /usr/local/tomee/webapps/host-manager/META-INF/context.xml
    13-Aug-2018 18:22:15.581 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication Deployed Application(path=/usr/local/tomee/webapps/host-manager)
    13-Aug-2018 18:22:15.632 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
    13-Aug-2018 18:22:15.650 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke Deployment of web application directory [/usr/local/tomee/webapps/host-manager] has finished in [154] ms
    13-Aug-2018 18:22:15.658 INFO [main] jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8084"]
    13-Aug-2018 18:22:15.682 INFO [main] jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
    13-Aug-2018 18:22:15.699 INFO [main] jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke Server startup in 1527 ms
```

**(7)**

*open tomee console in browser:*    http://localhost:8888